# Alitalia Delays - landed at final destination with 13 hours delay

Tags: air-travel

I recently flew from JFK to Tel AViv with a stop at Rome.
Our flight from New York was delayed by **6 hours**. They told us it's because the plane had to turn back to Rome because of a medical emergency.
As a result, they also had to reschedule our connection flight from Rome to Tel Aviv.

We landed at Rome 20 minutes before the connection flight, but they refused to let us on board, saying they have already sold our tickets.
They rescheduled our flight **(again)** to 8 hours later.

Eventually, instead of landing in Tel Aviv at 14:00pm, we landed at 03:00am.

Alitalia is refusing to compensate, claiming the airport at JFK caused the delay (which isn't what we were told at that day).

I live in Israel and they have offices here.
What can I do? I don't want to use any website that takes 25% of the compensation.

Should I simply file a lawsuit?

Comment: As far as EU compensations rules are concerned (I think they apply here?), whether the airport was responsible isn't relevant *per se*. The question is whether a medical emergency counts as “extraordinary circumstance”. Technical issues do not, and the [EU website](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm#apr-problems) even mentions the collision between mobile stairs and the aircraft (a typical airport issue) as something that would not free the airline from its obligations. But it does not mention isolated health emergencies either way…

Comment: The airline officially claims (by their email response) that the delay was because of a "Operations Control" at JFK, which they claim is included under extraordinary circumstances. The question is I should simply sue them

Comment: If you really want to go to all the trouble, you need to ask the right questions.  Primarily, what was the *exact* reason for the inbound delay to JFK.  Then, you need to figure out if that is the airline's responsibility.  If the TLV flights operated normally, you likely have no recourse there.  JFK very often has a flow control scheme due to thunderstorms and I can't in good conscious hold the airline responsible for a medical diversion.

Comment: The fact is that the airline is lying. They gave us 2 different reasons. The injustice that was done was worse on the Rome to TLV flight - they refused to let us board the plane, despite the fact it was on the ground and other people were boarding it in front of our eyes. My question is not whether I deserve compensations or not, but how do I get the compensation I deserve by law.

Comment: Please understand, there's a lot more going on than you see.  The airline staff, they're just people too, are not 'lying'.  The last delay reason they see for the flight may very well be due to flow control in to or out of JFK.  This happens all the time.  They'd have to look further back to see the medical diversion.  "We landed at Rome 20 minutes before the connection flight" - then you probably landed *after* the airline has to submit the final manifest to European and Israeli authorities.  There is nothing the airline can do about this.

Comment: @Johns-305 the airline must do all it can to claim circumstances beyond their control. Flow control in JFK is normal operation, not something extraordinary.

Comment: @GeorgeY. an in flight emergency requiring a diversion certainly would be something extraordinary. That's the real reason for ending up delayed out of JFK, the flow control just added a bit to it (potentially enough to make them miss the connection, but that's open for guesswork).

Comment: In fact, the flight from JFK was originally delayed from 6pm to 9:30pm. After we boarded the plane only at 10pm (another unexpected delay), we waited inside the plane for another 2.5 hours until 00:30am. They promised us that the connection flight from Rome will wait for us and that they know we're coming (we were 25 passengers needed to go on that connection flight), but what happens on the ground was different - we weren't allowed to board the plane from Rome to TLV. Then yes, I do believe we deserve the maximum compensation.

Comment: @GeorgeY. Sorry, no.  If you look at the write-ups on compensation, weather/ATC is beyond the airlines control and considered an extraordinary circumstances.  While it is common, *flow control is a safety measure* and is/should be rightly excluded from compensation.

Comment: @GuyManzur Unfortunately, the circumstances you've listed are all life/safety related and beyond the airline's control.  You need to research every step to find something that Alitalia did to cause the delay.  Also be aware that the airlines are not obligated to hold flights for connecting passengers and there are many regulator and contractual reasons why they can't be.  Since it seems the TLV flights operated normally, be prepared for them to argue that the only delay was on JFK-FCO and is not covered due to extraordinary circumstances, the aforementioned medical/ATC.

Comment: @Johns-305 if we listened to airline reps complains, absolutely everything is "extraordinary circumstance". This is why you should not. Just file the formal paperwork requesting compensation, at which moment 70% of "extraordinary circumstances" dry up. The rest go to court, at which moment remaining 20% are settled. I collected over $1000 in compensation this year alone. Only one airline refused the written request, but settled it as soon as they were served court papers.

Comment: @GeorgeY. While you may have had valid claims, I'm not suggesting OP forego the attempt.  I'm merely suggesting OP identify a circumstance that is within the airline's control and ATC and medical diversions are...well...not.  Random example of ATC specifically identified as a 'extraordinary circumstance' not due compensation: http://www.bottonline.co.uk/flight-delay-compensation/claim-guides/flight-compensation-bad-weather

Comment: @Johns-305 you're missing the point. It is not enough for circumstance to be out of airline control; mechanical failures certainly are. The law however requires the airline to do everything it can to avoid delays - so the airline has to prove that the flow control was totally unexpected and could not be predicted with due diligence. This is something nobody would believe for JFK, where it is more like a norm.

Comment: @GeorgeY. I'm not missing any point at all.  Even the UK CAA lists airport flow control as exempt from compensation: https://www.caa.co.uk/Passengers/Resolving-travel-problems/Delays-cancellations/Your-rights/Am-I-entitled-to-compensation-/  ATC is out of the airlines control, it is as simple as that provided they are otherwise ready to fly.  And here under "Are there exceptions?" (yes, ATC) http://www.telegraph.co.uk/travel/advice/How-to-claim-compensation-when-a-flight-is-delayed/

Comment: You certainly didn't read my comment above.

Answer (score 3):

[Israel has its own law](http://www.tourism-law.co.il/pdf/AviationServicesLawENG.pdf) regarding compensations for delays and cancellations. [Here is a summary from Delta](https://www.delta.com/content/dam/delta-www/pdfs/legal/passenger_rights_israel.pdf). For an arrival of more than 8hr late you're eligible for 3070 NIS. No need to involve EU rules at all.

So just file a written compensation request against their Tel Aviv offices, and if refused, go to a small claims court. Do not waste your time emailing them if they are not cooperating.